# how can i solve lstm dimension error in keras?

Tags: python, keras

Here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))
```

I got this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (62796, 1)
```

if I set `return_sequences=True` then output shape is 3D array

So, why this error occur??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input and output of the keras LSTM layer should be 3 dimensional, and by default follows the shape,

(Batch_size, Time_steps, Features).

It seems like you are using only two dimensions (62796, 1) from you error message.

following is a minimal working example with synthetic data, which illustrate the input and output shape required by your LSTM network.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout
import numpy as np

numb_outputs = 1

batch_size = 10
timesteps = 5
features = 2

x_single_batch = np.random.rand(batch_size, timesteps, features)
y_single_batch = np.random.rand(batch_size, timesteps, numb_outputs)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(numb_outputs, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
model.fit(x= x_single_batch, y=y_single_batch)
```

Comment: if i use ```create_dataset``` then ```y_train``` shape is (62796, ) So, how can i reshape this data? ```x_train``` shape is (62796, 20) so i just ```x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)``` but i can't solve ```y_train``` reshape

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this tutorial https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/
If I should try to help I think I need more information about your data. do you have a time-series with 62796 time steps, where x_train for each time steps you have 20 features?
if so, I suggest splitting your data into batches each of size t_max and train the data. you can use "Memory Between Batches" to achieve close to single time series behavior. then X will be (62796/t_max, t_max, 20) and Y will be (62796/t_max, t_max, 1)

Comment: you could also try a single large batch like, x of size (1, 62796, 20) and y of size (1, 62796, 1). I do not think this is a common method for LSTM (especially when the dataset becomes large), so I guess it will probably cause some computation, memory or efficiency problems... if you try both suggestions, I would love to hear you result and experience!